# java.lang.Long in C#

Tags: c#, java, types

I'm developing a WCF JSON Web Service which receive data from an Android application.

Some data could be null. On Android I'm using [java.lang.Long](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html), that could be `null`.

On C#side, I'm using `long` that couldn't be `null`.

Is there a `java.lang.Long` type in C#?

Comment: @SayemAhmed it is in fact `long` and can not be null.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you want a `Nullable<long>` or `long?`.

```
long? myLongVar = null;
if (myLongVar == null) // or !myLongVar.HasValue, if you prefer
{
    myLongVar = 5L;
    long noLongerNullable = myLongVar.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Nullable` type in c#

```
Long? x;//by default x is now null..you can now assign null to it
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `long?` aka `Nullable<long>`

Comment: Huh?  Same answer as everyone else gave in that same 60 second window of time after the question was posetd.

Comment: The low-quality queue doesn't give me that much context, and you phrased it like a question. :-)

Comment: Ah, the question mark...looks like there needs to be a C#-aware filter for the "low-quality queue" given it is a language construct.  Still, it is interesting the stuff that goes on behind the scene to keep SO running and moderated.  Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Ah, learned something new today, you actually *meant* for that question mark to be part of the keyword there. :-) I missed that the first time round, btw.